# Reactjs Spring-boot security

Tags: authentication, spring-security, reactjs, spring-boot

I have developed an application with react in front and spring-boot in backend.
I havent implemented any login page yet. I started to look for an example to start with. There aren't many example in this setting and many of examples are outdated.
Is there anyone who can point me to an example? or show me atleast how it shouuld be done.
I am using react 0.14.0

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question.  What makes a login form implementation using React any different from a standard JSP or HTML page?  You need a form with a username and password field, that has a POST action to whatever endpoint that you've configured spring security to use.  You should be able to follow any guide for spring security and do just fine.  Did you have a specific question that you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 1):

React is doesn't make any decisions for you about your backend or how it gets delivered (you can serve it to a client with literally anything that can send HTTP/TCP to a browser). If you're using node.js as a backend, you can use the runtime to execute JavaScript and use some methods available to React-DOM to do some server-side rendering. Aside from that, React only runs client-side and will "take over" DOM manipulation once it instantiates and starts running in the browser.

As far as login and security go, that again is completely up to whatever language and server framework you use. You can use vanilla JS or an HTTP library to send credentials to your server, but React isn't concerned with server-side security.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In side ReactJs Login Component call handle function on submit of the login form:

```
handleClick(event){
     axios.post("http://localhost:8080/username="+this.state.username+"&password="+this.state.password).then(function (response) {
       if(response.data.code === 200){
           window.location('http://localhost:8080/hello')
       } else {
         console.log(response.data.code);
       }
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
     });
     }
```

Inside security config file the following code is used as follows:

```
      @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/hello/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/")
                        .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("hello", true)
                        .and()
                        .httpBasic()
                .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
            }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                   auth
                    .inMemoryAuthentication()
                      .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER")
             .and()
                     .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
                }
```