# Implementing Spring Security in Sprint boot with ReactJS

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement basic login authentication of username and password with Spring Security using Spring Boot and ReactJS. I tried to do it with few examples online but mostly everything is with respect to JSP's and nothing with ReactJS. I am able to do run this with default login of Spring Security but when i am trying to do the custom login page using ReactJS. I am unable to find a way of doing it. Any help or pointers are highly appreciated.

```
**login.html**



 var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
           return {
            username: "",
            password: ""
            };
        },
        _onSubmit: function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();

              var data = {
                    username: this.state.username,
                    password: this.state.password
                }

                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/login",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function(data){

                    }.bind(this),
                    error:function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data.responseJSON.message);
                    }
                });

        },
        _onUserNameChange: function (event) {
            this.setState({username: event.target.value});
        },
        _onPasswordChange: function (event) {
            this.setState({password: event.target.value});
        },
      render: function() {
    return (
      <Grommet.App>
        <Box pad='medium' align='center' >
          <Box pad={{ vertical: 'medium', horizontal: 'medium', between: 'medium' }} align='center'>
          </Box>
          <Box size='large' pad='medium'>
            <Section align='center' pad='small' separator='top'>
              <Label margin='none' uppercase={true}>Tool</Label>
            </Section>
          </Box>
          <Form pad='medium'>
            <FormField label='User Name' error={this.state.usernameError}>
              <input type='text' value={this.state.username} onChange={this._onUserNameChange} />
            </FormField>
            <FormField label='Password' value={this.state.password} onChange={this._onPasswordChange} error={this.state.passwordError}>
              <input type='password' />
            </FormField>
            <Footer pad={{ vertical: 'medium' }} direction='column'>
              <Button label='Login' primary={true} fill={true} onClick={this._onSubmit} type="submit" name="submit" />
            </Footer>
          </Form>
        </Box>
      </Grommet.App>
    );
      }

      });

        var element = document.getElementById('content');
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), element);




 **SecurityConfig.java**


 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/*").hasRole("USER")
        .and()
    .formLogin()
         .loginProcessingUrl("/login.html");
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");

}
```

}

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: @aliakbarazizkhani I dont know how to make it work using reactjs /login post. I have seen examples on JSP but not react.

Comment: This may help [checkout this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201989/reactjs-spring-boot-security/45759806#45759806)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the path for Login Processing URL: you are posting your credentials from ReactJS to the ***/login*** url, but in the spring security config you are listening to the ***/login.html***.

Just change the configuration to:

```
 .loginProcessingUrl("/login");
```

I think it will be ok.
Good luck!